# Retraining a classifier with training data from different images

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am in the process of conducting a multitemporal image classification in Earth Engine using training data from specific images within an ImageCollection. So far, I was able to classify an image from one day where I had field data (see my code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/457d598d3c6e5a6d93b8131c636b5408)).

However, I need guidance on how to retrain the Random Forest classifier with training data from additional days (for example *image_2* and *image_3* in the code). In other words, I will like to build a classifier that does not only consider one image of training data (`image` and `nwfc` in the code), but several FeatureCollections that I created for different images (for example, FeatureColllections `newfc_2` and `newfc_3` in the code).

After this step is done, I would like to apply that retrained classifier to the whole ImageCollection (`collection` in the code).

Comment: Could you please add your code here instead of giving a link?

Comment: The code is longer than the allowed space.